# Customizing Built-In Components

Tags: getstream-io

I'm currently in the process of testing out Stream to see if it will be viable for use in an upcoming React project.  One thing I have not been able to find an example of is the ability to extensively customize some of the built-in React Stream components.  For example, the functionality of StatusUpdateForm is great, but unfortunately, the layout of the component doesn't really work for my use case.

Is there currently a way to utilize the existing functionality of the built-in components while changing the layout or adding/removing some functionality without simply having to roll my own component from scratch?

Thanks!